# Wordpress loop displays not only the posts

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, while-loop, posts

I've got the following code:

```
    <div id="container" class="activiteiten_singleview">

        <div id="content_activiteiten">
            <h1 id="pagetitle"><?php echo get_the_title($ID);?></h1>

             <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                    if ( is_page('48') ) {
                        query_posts( 'cat=4' );
                    }
                    if ( is_page('44') ) {
                        query_posts( 'cat=6' );
                    }
                    if ( is_page('46') ) {
                        query_posts( 'cat=9' );
                    }
                    if ( is_page('50') ) {
                        query_posts( 'cat=8' );
                    }
                    if ( is_page('52') ) {
                        query_posts( 'cat=7' );
                    }?>


                    <div class="postwrapper">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    </div>

                 <?php endwhile; endif;?>


        </div>
    </div><!-- #container -->
```

The problem is that not only the posts are created in the postwrapper-div, but also the page title with an empty excerpt. I only want to show all the posts as a postwrapper.

Comment: try echo the_excerpt();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 

if ( is_page('48') ) {
    query_posts( 'cat=4' );
}
if ( is_page('44') ) {
    query_posts( 'cat=6' );
}
if ( is_page('46') ) {
    query_posts( 'cat=9' );
}
if ( is_page('50') ) {
    query_posts( 'cat=8' );
}
if ( is_page('52') ) {
    query_posts( 'cat=7' );
}

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="postwrapper">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: This changes nothing. The postwrapper with the page title and no content is still there.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to show all your queried posts within **one** postwrapper?

Comment: I want to show all queried posts in a different postwrapper, this works. But the loop creates the first postwrapper not with the content from a post, but with the pagetitle in the h3 and the p is empty.

Comment: So I want that only the posts are created.

Comment: Remove `<h1 id="pagetitle"><?php echo get_the_title($ID);?></h1>` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it inside a page template try adding query_posts

```
<div id="container" class="activiteiten_singleview">

        <div id="content_activiteiten">
            <h1 id="pagetitle"><?php echo get_the_title($ID);?></h1>

             <?php query_posts('post_type=post'); if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                    if ( is_page('48') ) {
                        query_posts( 'cat=4' );
                    }
                    if ( is_page('44') ) {
                        query_posts( 'cat=6' );
                    }
                    if ( is_page('46') ) {
                        query_posts( 'cat=9' );
                    }
                    if ( is_page('50') ) {
                        query_posts( 'cat=8' );
                    }
                    if ( is_page('52') ) {
                        query_posts( 'cat=7' );
                    }?>


                    <div class="postwrapper">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    </div>

                 <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


        </div>
    </div><!-- #container -->
```