# Wordpress looping posts: The loop doesn't show only posts

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, while-loop, posts

I've got the following loop to show different posts from a specific category on a page in the div 'postwrapper'.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

if ( is_page('48') ) {
   query_posts( 'cat=4' );
}
if ( is_page('44') ) {
   query_posts( 'cat=6' );
}

   <div class="postwrapper">
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  
      <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
   </div>

<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

The problem is that the loop shows not only the posts, but also creates a postwrapper div with the page name. How can I fix thi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress loop displays not only the posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398546/wordpress-loop-displays-not-only-the-posts)

Comment: Belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/